# Can this sentence be parsed using this grammar?

Tags: parsing, nlp, grammar, parse-tree

Here is a selection of a lexicon and a grammar

> Noun -> stench | breeze | wumpus | pits ...
>
> Verb -> is | feels | smells | smell | see | stinks ...
>
> Adjective -> right | dead | smelly | breezy ...
>
> Adverb -> here | ahead | nearby ...
>
> Pronoun -> me | you | I | it ...
>
> RelPro -> that | which | who | whom ...
>
> Name -> John | Mary | Boston ...
>
> Article -> the | a | an | every ...
>
> Prep -> to | in | on | near ...
>
> Conj -> and | or | but | yet ...
>
> Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ...

Grammar rules is below:

> S -> NP VP            | S Conj S
>
> NP -> Pronoun     | Namae    | Noun     | Article Noun     | Article
>   Adjs Noun     | Digit Digit     | NP PP     | NP RelClause
>
> VP -> Verb    | VP NP    | VP Adjective    | VP PP    | VP Adverb
>
> Adjs -> Adjective     | Adjective Adjs
>
> PP -> Prep NP
>
> RelClause -> RelPro VP

The Question: Is this sentence "Mary smells the wumpus in the pit that stinks." generated by this grammar?

My Answer: No, because "pit" was not defined in the grammar.

Question from me to experts at nlp: Is my logic and understanding of parse trees correct in and my given answer correct?  the reason it could not be generated because "pit" was not defined in the grammar. Note: I am able to create a parse tree and draw it, if i change the sentence to "pits".

Comment: I think your answer is right! Parsing will fail as `pit` is not defined!

Comment: The new problem I'm having is in my subject guide. A proper parse example had the sentence being generated: "I feel a breeze." 
Now "feel" isn't specified in the grammar either so is it a typo or something? By the way this is not the subject NLP i am doing i am doing AI and this is a chapter in my book. I wonder if they are probably not getting into the details of subject verb agreement and stuff to keep stuff simple?

Comment: "I feel a breeze" won't generate a parse tree since your grammar doesn't define "feel" instead defines "feels"!

Comment: are you 100% sure...because I am still learning this stuff...If you are sure i will consider it a typo in the book..Thanks!

Comment: I won't say that I am 100% sure, but since you are referring a book, there's a possibility of a typo!

Comment: I suppose that the `...` at the end of each lexical list has its usual meaning of "and so on"; that is, the extract is only showing you a representative sample of the full lexicon, and the authors are expecting you to be able to figure out which grammatical category each word fits into. (I was going to say something about native English speakers but on reflection, I think that second-language learning might give you a better grasp on grammatical concepts, since native language understanding is more intuitive than analytic. Still, it should be easy to predict where `pit` belongs.)

Comment: @rici so i should assume that pit is already in the lexicon even though it is not shown (under the Noun category of course!) ?